# Difficulty with a global/shared counter when using a multiprocessing.pool that processes lines in a file (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have converted a Python program that processes lines in a text file to use multi-threading (this is **in Python 2.7**), and that was a great improvement in performance. I also added a global counter variable to indicate progress as it's running and reporting when complete. It seemed to work ok. But now **I'm updating it for Python 3** and running into issues. It doesn't print the counter at all while in-progress, and it's actually printed as 0 at the end. **I need for this counter to be updated throughout its processing so it can report progress.**

I've researched and I read that Python copies everything for a new thread and I could definitely see how that happens. And I've seen different strategies including using a Value(), Lock(), but I'm struggling with implementation. And a lot of examples I've seen use a different multi-threading function that might be starting a batch of threads in one line (map_async).

I'm new to both Python and multi-threading so I will ask about this. Performance does matter here, so it would be nice to keep it asynchronous. The counter should increment after the line is processed since that processing is where all the time is spent. I'll note that I am perfectly fine with a global variable or two here.

Let me go back to my working version for Python 2.7 and genericize and shink it down (below). Actually, when I do that and cut out the meat of what it's doing when processing lines in the file, it does show the correct number of lines tested at the end.

I appreciate any help!

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from datetime import datetime

pool_size = 10  #"parallelness"
progress_output_interval = 20  #reporting frequency (by number of lines processed)

found_matched_line = False
found_matched_line_val = ''
count_lines_tested = 0
count_batches_tested = 0

start_time = datetime.now()


def process_file (file_name, process_function, param1, param2, param3, param4):
  
  pool = Pool(pool_size)
  
  global found_matched_line
  global count_batches_tested 
  batch = ['0'] * pool_size
  curr_batch_size = 0;
  end_of_file = False
  
  #open input file
  f = open (file_name, 'r')
  
  #loop to go through lines of input file
  while not end_of_file and not found_matched_line: 
    
    #read lines and build a batch
    curr_batch_size = 0
    for i in range(pool_size):
      curr_line = f.readline ()
      if not curr_line: 
        end_of_file = True #empty string, not even a newline
      else: 
        curr_line = curr_line.rstrip ()
        batch[i] = curr_line
        curr_batch_size += 1
    
    #loop through items in current batch
    for j in range(curr_batch_size):
      curr_line2 = batch[j]
      if not curr_line2: 
        print ('Info - skipping blank line')
      else: 
        #multithreaded call to the worker function given by process_function
        if process_function == 'process_line_function1':
          pool.apply_async(process_line_function1, (curr_line2, param1, param2, param3, param4))
        elif process_function == 'process_line_function2':
          pool.apply_async(process_line_function2, (curr_line2, param1, param2, param3))
        else: 
          print ('Error: unexpected process_function '+str(process_function))
    
    #increment batch number if had batch size bigger than 0. 
    #if batch size = 0, we finished the end of the file on an even filled batch
    if curr_batch_size > 0:
      count_batches_tested += 1
            
  pool.close() #no more work can be submitted to pool
  pool.join() #ensures all threads finish before continuing program
  f.close () #close input file
  
  return


def process_line_function1 (line, param1, param2, param3, param4):
  
  match_found = False
  #do bunch of stuff here to check for match using params
  
  time.sleep(.3)
  
  if match_found: 
    global found_matched_line
    found_matched_line = True
    global found_matched_line_val
    found_matched_line_val = line
    print ('Found a match: '+found_matched_line_val)
  
  ####################
  #update progress
  global count_lines_tested
  count_lines_tested += 1
  now_time = datetime.now()
  if (count_lines_tested % progress_output_interval) == 0:
    overall_elapsed_time = getElapsedTime(start_time, now_time)
    overall_elapsed_time_seconds_decimal = (now_time - start_time).total_seconds()
    overall_rate = '{:.2f}'.format(count_lines_tested/overall_elapsed_time_seconds_decimal)
    print (str(count_lines_tested)+' tested'+', elapsed: '+overall_elapsed_time+', rate: '+overall_rate+' lines/sec')
  ####################
  
  return
  
  
def process_line_function2 (line, param1, param2, param3):
  #similar to process_line_function1
  return



#
# START / main:
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  #get input file name
  file_name = sys.argv[1]
  
  process_line_function = '';
  #do some other stuff here to help determine needed process_function
  if True:
    process_line_function = 'process_line_function1'
  else:
    process_line_function = 'process_line_function2'
    
  param1 = 'blah';
  param2 = 'blah2';
  param3 = 'blah3';
  param4 = 'blah4';
  
  #process the file
  process_file (file_name, process_line_function, param1, param2, param3, param4)
  
  #do final reporting
  end_time = datetime.now()
  elapsed_time_seconds_decimal = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
  final_rate = "{:.2f}".format(count_lines_tested/elapsed_time_seconds_decimal)
  print ('Started at: '+start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  print ('Finished at: '+end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  print (str(count_lines_tested)+' lines tested (in '+str(count_batches_tested)+' batches)')
  print ('Rate: '+final_rate+' lines/second')
  if found_matched_line: 
    print ('MATCH WAS FOUND! --- '+found_matched_line_val)
  else: 
    print ('Match was not found')
  
  sys.exit (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured out how to use Value() to have a shared counter that actually works with the multi-threading while in progress and when finished. I did keep my same pool.apply_async() call, but the pool actually has the counter (Value()) included when it's initialized now. The new version I'll put below does print the progress periodically as intended and at the end.

I found I have other issues yet to deal with in the change from Python 2.7 to 3.9, but that's related to the code I pulled out for this minimum example.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from multiprocessing import Value

from datetime import datetime

pool_size = 10  #"parallelness"
progress_output_interval = 20  #reporting frequency (by number of lines processed)

found_matched_line = False
found_matched_line_val = ''
count_batches_tested = 0

count_lines_tested = None

start_time = datetime.now()

def init(args):
    #store the counter for later use
    global count_lines_tested
    count_lines_tested = args


def process_file (file_name, process_function, param1, param2, param3, param4):
  
  count_lines_tested = Value('i', 0)
  pool = Pool(initializer = init, initargs = (count_lines_tested, ))
  
  global found_matched_line
  global count_batches_tested 
  batch = ['0'] * pool_size
  curr_batch_size = 0;
  end_of_file = False
  
  #open input file
  f = open (file_name, 'r')
  
  #loop to go through lines of input file
  while not end_of_file and not found_matched_line: 
    
    #read lines and build a batch
    curr_batch_size = 0
    for i in range(pool_size):
      curr_line = f.readline ()
      if not curr_line: 
        end_of_file = True #empty string, not even a newline
      else: 
        curr_line = curr_line.rstrip ()
        batch[i] = curr_line
        curr_batch_size += 1
    
    #loop through items in current batch
    for j in range(curr_batch_size):
      curr_line2 = batch[j]
      if not curr_line2: 
        print ('Info - skipping blank line')
      else: 
        #multithreaded call to the worker function given by process_function
        if process_function == 'process_line_function1':
          pool.apply_async(process_line_function1, (curr_line2, param1, param2, param3, param4))
        elif process_function == 'process_line_function2':
          pool.apply_async(process_line_function2, (curr_line2, param1, param2, param3))
        else: 
          print ('Error: unexpected process_function '+str(process_function))
    
    #increment batch number if had batch size bigger than 0. 
    #if batch size = 0, we finished the end of the file on an even filled batch
    if curr_batch_size > 0:
      count_batches_tested += 1
            
  pool.close() #no more work can be submitted to pool
  pool.join() #ensures all threads finish before continuing program
  f.close () #close input file
  
  return


def process_line_function1 (line, param1, param2, param3, param4):
  
  match_found = False
  #do bunch of stuff here to check for match using params
  
  time.sleep(.3)
  
  if match_found: 
    global found_matched_line
    found_matched_line = True
    global found_matched_line_val
    found_matched_line_val = line
    print ('Found a match: '+found_matched_line_val)
  
  ####################
  #update progress
  global count_lines_tested
  with count_lines_tested.get_lock():
    count_lines_tested.value += 1
    if (count_lines_tested.value % progress_output_interval == 0):
      now_time = datetime.now()
      overall_elapsed_time = getElapsedTime(start_time, now_time)
      overall_elapsed_time_seconds_decimal = (now_time - start_time).total_seconds()
      overall_rate = '{:.2f}'.format(count_lines_tested.value/overall_elapsed_time_seconds_decimal)
      print (str(count_lines_tested.value)+' tested'+', elapsed: '+overall_elapsed_time+', rate: '+overall_rate+' lines/sec')
  ####################
  
  return
  
  
def process_line_function2 (line, param1, param2, param3):
  #similar to process_line_function1
  return


#
# START / main:
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  #get input file name
  file_name = sys.argv[1]
  
  process_line_function = '';
  #do some other stuff here to help determine needed process_function
  if True:
    process_line_function = 'process_line_function1'
  else:
    process_line_function = 'process_line_function2'
    
  param1 = 'blah';
  param2 = 'blah2';
  param3 = 'blah3';
  param4 = 'blah4';
  
  #process the file
  process_file (file_name, process_line_function, param1, param2, param3, param4)
  
  #do final reporting
  end_time = datetime.now()
  elapsed_time_seconds_decimal = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
  final_rate = "{:.2f}".format(count_lines_tested.value/elapsed_time_seconds_decimal)
  print ('Started at: '+start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  print ('Finished at: '+end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  print (str(count_lines_tested.value)+' lines tested (in '+str(count_batches_tested)+' batches)')
  print ('Rate: '+final_rate+' lines/second')
  if found_matched_line: 
    print ('MATCH WAS FOUND! --- '+found_matched_line_val)
  else: 
    print ('Match was not found')
  sys.exit (1)
```